# ng-repeat not working after upgrading from angularjs 1.0.8 to 1.2.3

Tags: angularjs

I recently upgraded from angularjs 1.0.8 to 1.2.3 and it has been a nightmare. So many things have broken, some of which I have been able to figure out. There is a problem with `ng-repeat` that I have been unable to fix. When using 1.0.8 the following code worked as expected:

```
<ul id="my_list">
    <li ng-click="doSomething('{{item.item_id}}')" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>This is item {{item.item_id}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, now that I have upgraded to 1.2.3 each `<li>` will display the `item_id` in the `<span>` (i.e., "This is item 1", "This is item 2", etc.), but the function still just displays `doSomething('{{item.item_id}}')` as opposed to, for example, `doSomething('1')`. Why is `{{item.item_id}}` binding in one place, but not the other?

Comment: try doSomething(item.item_id)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` takes a JS expression, so `<li ng-click="doSomething(item.item_id)" ng-repeat="item in items">` should work.

Answer (score 1):

`ngClick` doesn't interpolate the expression. Use `doSomething(item.item_id)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff and ceejayoz point out `ng-click` expects an Angular expression, so you can access scope properties without binding to them.

Use this if you need the parameter as a string:

```
ng-click="doSomething(item.item_id.toString())"
```

For adding the value in the DOM you need the curly braces, which tell Angular to expect an expression like `ng-click` does.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because I wrote the function with a semicolon as the end: `doSomething('{{item.item_id}}');`. I found that `onclick="doSomething('{{item.item_id}}')"` doesn't work, but `ng-click="doSomething('{{item.item_id}}')"` does work.

As a side note: I have been working with angularjs for about 5 months now, and I have to say that it has led to an increase in the complexity of my apps and it is much more complicated that just using jquery. I know many people will disagree, but it just seems like it is MUCH more trouble than its worth. I kind of regret using it.

Comment: If you're seeing *more* complexity, I'd say you're doing it wrong or you're using it for the wrong things...

Comment: Don't worry, I felt the same at first, but now i'm on another up like Ben Nadel's graph here, http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm

Comment: If it helps, i'd recommend trying some restructuring and refactoring. My apps started to get to clogged up and I started moving away from the common structure to one that's used here: http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza
that is: app => controllers, directives, services

Comment: Then as the app grew I went to a similar structure but to one based on the function then the above structure. E.g app => directive => userAccounts, app => controllers => userAccounts etc. This helped to keep my code decoupled and made it a lot easier to read and work with. It took me a while to refactor tp the new structure but it was 100% worth it.